# How to set right alignment of some text using NotesRichTextParagraphStyle

Tags: xpages

```
var currDb:NotesDatabase = session.getCurrentDatabase();
var emailDoc:NotesDocument = database.createDocument();
var mailRTItem:NotesRichTextItem = emailDoc.createRichTextItem("Body");
var mStyle:NotesRichTextStyle = session.createRichTextStyle();
var r:NotesRichTextParagraphStyle = session.createRichTextParagraphStyle();
mStyle.setBold(1);
mailRTItem.appendStyle(mStyle);
mailRTItem.appendText(@Text("Dear Concerned,"));
mailRTItem.addNewLine(2);
r.setRightMargin(1);
mailRTItem.appendParagraphStyle(r);
mailRTItem.appendText("Text That is required to be right aligned");
emailDoc.save();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, choc. For future questions you need to add a description of your problem and not just code

Comment: For better fidelity on web and email platforms other than Notes, the best practice approach would be to use MIME emails rather than Rich Text styles.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code line

```
r.setRightMargin(1);
```

with the line

```
r.setAlignment(NotesRichTextParagraphStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT);
```

This will set the right alignment.